# Database not created Code first EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I do not understand why my code does not work. I have a model:

```
    public class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a Context:

```
    public class BetContext : DbContext
    {
        public BetContext()
            : base("name=Bet")
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        }
    }
```

My ConnectionString:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Bet" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=PK01;     Initial Catalog=Bet;Integrated Security=True;     MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

My GlobalAsax:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
            Database.SetInitializer(new  InitializerDb());
        }
```

My ConnectToServer:
[ConnectToServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuAFb.png)

My Initializer:

```
    public class InitializerDb : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BetContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BetContext context)
        {
            var client = new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    Id = 1 , Surname = "Lalala" , Name = "Paxan" , DateOfBirthday = DateTime.Now, Email = "lalll",
                    Password = "123445" , Phone = "12345"
                }
            };
            client.ForEach(s => context.Clients.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I am stuck. Please tell me why this code is not creating a new database in SQL Server?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is it hitting the Seed() code? Try DropCreateDatabaseAlways and see if that runs.

Comment: no errors. I tried DropCreateDatabaseAlways but problem is stayed

Comment: did you try putting a breakpoint at the seed method and see if it is being hit?

Comment: yes, I put a breakpoint at the seed method. Its not hit into the Seed method!

Comment: Are you running a command that actually uses the context? Try adding db.Database.Initialize(true);

Comment: Thanks all! I decide my problem

Comment: It was most likely an issue of lazy loading (asp.net's default).  Basically the database won't be created until the application actually needs to use it. (when you create your first instance of an object in the system that is saved through a model, your database should create)